# OpenLayer 4 popup, prevent pointer to target data behind a div

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers

I have a problem with the Popup of OpenLayers 4, when I open the popup info and I'm inside the div with the pointer, it still triggering the hover popup with the data behind the popup, how can I prevent that?

I'm using this CSS code for the popup:

```
#popup {
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

The popup is created with the overlay layer:

```
overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});
```

But the pointer still passes through the div. the popup contains a lot of `div` and inside `span`

In the screenshot the hover popup was triggered when the pointer was on the `Vehs` text

[image]

You can refer to this for the code I use for the popup, the only difference is that I have a hover popup, I think the problem is on the creation of the click popup (the one with button) and the real z-index of it.

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found a very simple way to solve the problem, inside the function I call for the hover popup I add a simple `if` statement

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {

    info.html("");

    if (overlay.getPosition() !== undefined) {
      return;
    }
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointer-events:none` before its open and  `pointer-events:all` once it's in open state

Comment: with `pointer-events:none` it will disable also the button isn't? the blue one is a button and I need to be able to click on it

Comment: sorry you meant when the popup is open it triggers behind elements hover popup? If that's the case you can use pseudo `:before` and make it transparent covered fully. So that it will act as layer between popup and content..

Comment: yes, the other `div` you see behind the popup, the one with a list it starts behind `Vehs` and was trigger when the mouse was on `Vehs` text

Comment: or you can make that div full screen and add inner div to show your content making the outer div transparent. Both will work for you. :)

Comment: is what we use on the mobile version but on desktop they want a popup, so is not a solution :(

Comment: I tried `pointer-events:none` but it doesn't solve the problem, it seems that the `z-index` of the pointer doesn't change when you enter the popup